# Python - Multiprocessing changes socket's value

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, multiprocessing, md5

I'm trying to program an MD5 decryptor which uses LAN to decrypt, and using all the available CPU on each PC.
The client code:

```
import socket
import multiprocessing as mp
import select
import re
import hashlib
import sys

def decryptCall(list,text):
    rangeNums = int(list[1]) - int(list[0]) + 1
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print my_socket
        print "ok"
        decrypt(list[i], int(list[i]) + rangeNums, text)
        #p = mp.Process(target=decrypt,args=(list[i], int(list[i]) + rangeNums, text))
        #p.start()
        #processes.append(p)

def end():
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print my_socket

    print "goodbye"
    sys.exit()
def decrypt(low,high,text):
    counter = int(low)
    high = int(high)
    while counter <= high:
        m = hashlib.new('md5')
        m.update(str(counter))
        if str(m.hexdigest()).lower() == str(text.lower()):
            print "final: " + str(counter)
            my_socket.send(str(counter))
            end()
        counter+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    dataList = []
    q = mp.Queue()
    ADDR = ('127.0.0.1', 1337)
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    my_socket.connect(ADDR)
    my_socket.send(str(mp.cpu_count()))

    while True:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([my_socket], [my_socket], [])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            data = current_socket.recv(1024)
            if not re.search('[a-zA-Z]', data):
                dataList.append(data)
            else:
                md5hash = data
                print md5hash
                print dataList
                print my_socket
                decryptCall(dataList,md5hash)
```

The server code:

```
import time
import hashlib
import socket
import select
import msvcrt
import sys

open_client_sockets=[]

def decrypt(cpus2,text,):
    seperated = []
    place = 0
    low = 1000000
    high = 9999999
    numbers = high-low
    numbers /= cpus2
    for g in range(cpus2):
        seperated.append(low + numbers*g)
        print open_client_sockets[0]
    for g in range(len(open_client_sockets)):
        print str(g) + ": " + str(cpus.get(open_client_sockets[g]))
        for h in range(int(cpus.get(open_client_sockets[g]))):

            time.sleep(0.01)
            open_client_sockets[g].send(str(seperated[place]))
            place+=1
        open_client_sockets[g].send(text)
    test()

def test():
    print open_client_sockets[0].recv(10000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    md5hash2 = "fcea920f7412b5da7be0cf42b8c93759"
    messages_to_send=[]
    input = ''
    addresses = {}
    cpus = {}
    cpus_count=0
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1337))
    server_socket.listen(5)

    while True:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select( [server_socket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets,[])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is server_socket:
                (new_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()
                addresses[new_socket] = address
                open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
                #print addresses
            else:
                data = current_socket.recv(1024)
                cpus_count += int(data)
                cpus[current_socket] = data
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key = msvcrt.getch()
            sys.stdout.write(key)
            if key == '\r' and input != "":
                print "\nok"
                print cpus_count
                decrypt(cpus_count,md5hash2)
            input += key
```

The problem is, when I try to use multiprocessing:

```
 decrypt(list[i], int(list[i]) + rangeNums, text)
            p = mp.Process(target=decrypt,args=(list[i], int(list[i]) + rangeNums, text))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
```

The data isn't sent, because the socket's value changes. Example:

```
<socket._socketobject object at 0x029CAB58> -> <socket._socketobject object at 0x02941AE8>.
```

While trying to figure it out, I noticed something weird. 
Every time the program creates a new process, the socket's value changes.
When I use the normal call to function without multiprocessing, the socket stays as it is and the data is sent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fully formed answer( I'd leave a comment if my reputation was higher).  I believe what you are seeing is a result of trying to use a socket in a fork()d child that was established in a parent process (it's still open in the parent).  In this case you're probably getting a copy of the parent.

Some solutions:
You could establish a new socket in the child.
You could close the connection in the parent right after fork (or process start in this case).

For more reading lookup fork and socket, or multiprocessing and socket.